# Acoustic impedance of a compressed solid. Density as a vector?

Tags: acoustics

first post here. I've been looking into acoustics a bit recently and I'm wondering if for a compressed solid, acoustic impedance should change along different axis in certain cases.

Consider a cubic lattice of atoms with pressure being applied to the top and bottom, compressing the lattice. Atoms would be spaced further apart in planes parallel to the applied pressure.

I'm hypothesizing that acoustic impedance would be higher for a sound wave travelling through the lattice perpendicular to the plane of applied pressure and lower for a sound wave travelling through the lattice parallel to the plane of applied pressure.

Could we consider density as a vector to solve our impedance equation if the above holds true?

Comment: *...consider density as a vector...* no, (mass) density is definitely a scalar quantity.

Comment: Why not let the impedance itself exhibit the directional anisotropy?

Comment: There is no sensible way to make density into a vector. As far as pressure goes, it is the scalar trace of the stress tensor. Density may be related to the strain tensor. You can also contract these and higher order tensors with dyads of the wave vector to find something that makes geometric sense.